# Cannot create a Class Library Project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

When I'm trying to add a new Class Library Project in Visual Studio 2008 I get this error:

[image: Error message 1]

After clicking OK this message appear:

[image]

And then an directory was created with properties folder and AssemblyInfo.cs file only.

1. What caused this problem?
2. How to fix it?

**Edit:** when creating the project as a new project I got this message instead the second one:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages are hinting that components are missing or broken, and also the templates are missing some files. It seems like your installation of Visual Studio has become corrupt, try a repair or (in worst case) a complete reinstall of Visual Studio to fix this.

Comment: Right, but I have no idea I it was happen. I did work with vs regular, but I can't remember something special that can cause that.

Comment: Anyway, from searching the web I see that this is unknown error a all!

Answer (score 1):

your install is probably corrupt. see

[**Error HRESULT E_FAIL when pasting
   references in Visual Studio**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459111/error-hresult-e-fail-when-pasting-references-in-visual-studio)

Comment: According to the new message  don't think that is the case.

Comment: it is somehow, class1 is from the template that visual studio installation provides. If the path is not holding that file, The installation was not successful, though we might think it was.

Comment: follow the path and check if the file exist there !

Comment: VS check for the template at the path specified in its settings, it is included with install. You need to be careful about the version of VS, requirements and install order. These thing create a mess, lots of times.