# "Error HRESULT E_FAIL" using Class Designer in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, class-diagram

I am trying to show association relationships in my code using the Class Designer in Visual Studio 2015 (VB.NET). I am right clicking properties in my class and selecting `Show as Association`, which works correctly, and shows the association arrow.

However, when I try to use `Show as Collection Association` to show my many-to-one associations, I see the following dialog:

[Error Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sengI.png)

I have searched for *Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component*, but the common issues with this seem to be during compilation, or issues with the designer. Others with this problem report it appearings in the output window, rather than pop up in a message box like my error.

Things I have tried:

- repairing Visual Studio from Programs and Features in the Control Panel
- Creating a new class diaram, and trying to use the Collective Association feature
- suggestions from this thread: [Error HRESULT E_FAIL when pasting references in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459111/error-hresult-e-fail-when-pasting-references-in-visual-studio)

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: E_FAIL is just a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting, it doesn't tell anybody what actually went wrong.  Not you, not us.  Some features of VS were added *only* because some other IDE has the feature.  Like Eclipse, a formidable competitor with a very competitive price.  Nobody *actually* uses the feature, it is just a bullet point on the "why to buy" list.  So it is very buggy and basic problems like this never get sorted out.  You have to dial 1 (800) 642-7676 on your phone to get help.

Comment: [Report a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio) Not really anything we can tell you here. Someone with access to the VS2015 source code will need to look at it to figure out which COM component is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error trying to show a class diagram for a Xamarin.iOS project, while my Portable Class Libraies worked fine.

My low tech solution was to copy my classes to a temporary class library and make the diagram there...